# display tabs in header from left to right with some spaces

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React application with the following code:

```
export const AppHeaderBase: React.FunctionComponent<IAppHeaderProps> = (
  props: IAppHeaderProps
) => {
  const { className, styles } = props;
  const classNames: IProcessedStyleSet<IAppHeaderStyles> = getClassNames(
    styles,
    {
      className,
      theme: useTheme(),
    }
  );

  return (
    <header>
      <div className={classNames.root} role="banner" aria-label="header">
        <div>Welcome XYZ</div>
        <DefaultButton>Add</DefaultButton>
        <DefaultButton>Log Out</DefaultButton>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export const getStyles = (props: IAppHeaderStyleProps): IAppHeaderStyles => {
  const { className, theme } = props;

  return {
    root: [
      {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.themePrimary,
        height: 54,
        maxWidth: "100%",
        margin: '0 auto',
        borderBottom: '1px solid transparent',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        display: 'flex'
      },
      className
    ]
  };
};
```

The issue is I see all these in UI without any spaces in between

[image]

How do I update it such that there are equal spaces in between these 3?

Answer (score 0):

In your getStyles function you can add to root style this property:

```
root: [{
    justify-content: 'space-between';
}]
```